# how can I do some code before I build the form in Drupal 7 (kinda preprocess)?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, preprocessor, drupal-7

I'd like to ask how can I do some code before I build the form in Drupal 7?
Before defining a form I'd like to perform some code(I want to build an object), How can I do it?

The code i want to perform:

```
if (isset($_GET["team"])){$team = $_GET["team"];} else {$team=1; };
$myteam = new Team($team);
```

I define the form:

```
function teamform_nameform() { 
    $form['editteam']['team_city'] = array( 
    '#title' => t('Team city'), 
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#description' => t(''), 
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' =>**$myteam->returnCity()**,
        '#size' => 30, 
     );
$form['editteam']['submitContentChanges'] = array( 
     '#type' => 'submit', 
     '#value' => t('Save changes'),
     '#submit' => array('teamform_editteam_submitContentChanges'),
);
}
```

I tried to use the following hook, but it doesn't work. (i still can't get access to variable `$team` and to the object `$myteam` (it's written that they are undefined))

```
/** 
 *  Implements hook_form_alter(). 
 */ 

   function teamform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
     global $team;
     if (isset($_GET["team"])){$team = $_GET["team"];} else {$team=2;};
     global $myteam
     $myteam = new Team($team);
   }
```

$team is the team id which i get using method GET or if it's not set than i assign the default value. $myteam is a object which i build based on the team_id. 
Than I'd like to get access to the object in the function teamform_nameform(). In this function i use method returnCity() in order to return the city which the team belongs to; as a default value.
Than I'd like to make changes with the object. Specifically, when the user changes the city of the team and click submit button then i want to update the city in the object $myteam. Therefore i use the function:

```
function teamform_editteam_submitContentChanges($form, &$form_state){
  $team_city=$form_state['values']['team_city'];
  $myteam->updateTeamCity($team_city); //i got the error here. it's said that $myteam is undefined!
}
```

Comment: It must be simple, I used before `$modulename_preprocess_$hook()` for page prerendering.

Comment: Can I use `hook_init()` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want an object to persist across page loads, does that sound right?  If that's the case, you can store it in the session.  Try something like this:

```php
/** 
 *  Implements hook_form_alter(). 
 */ 
function teamform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  $team = isset($_GET["team"]) ? $_GET["team"] : 2;
  $_SESSION['team'] = new Team($team);
}
```

```php
function teamform_editteam_submitContentChanges($form, &$form_state){
  $team_city = $form_state['values']['team_city'];

  $myteam = $_SESSION['team'];
  $myteam->updateTeamCity($team_city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) allows you to modify the form before it's rendered including adding the `#default_value` property.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But how to use it in my case?There are three parameters in this function.

Comment: @alexey: Looks like your problem may not be Drupal specific hence I added the php tag to your question.  Perhaps you can add more detail as to where you're getting the `$team` variable from and the big picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my post, added the big picture of what I'm gonna do.